# Webpack 4 - Как импортировать файлы, если их много?

Tags: javascript, node.js, импорт, webpack4, require

Коллеги, есть такая простая **`Webpack`** сборка.

```
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

const minimizerBlock = {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                warnings: false,
                parse: {},
                compress: {},
                mangle: true,                    
                output: null,
                toplevel: false,
                nameCache: null,
                ie8: false,
                keep_fnames: false,
            },
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
}

const config = {
    entry: { main: './public/src/index.js' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',

    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 8888,
        overlay: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: { loader: "babel-loader" } },
            { test: /\.less$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "less-loader"] },
            { test: /\.scss$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"] },
            { test: /\.sass$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"] },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|webp)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './public/binary/image/')
                ],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'image/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './public/binary/fonts/')
                ],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp3)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './public/binary/audio/')
                ],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'audio/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                }]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: './index.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/src/', 'template.html'),
            filename: 'index.html',
            favicon: 'public/binary/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png'
        })

    ]
};
module.exports = (env, options) => {
    let production = options.mode == 'production';
    config.devtool = production ? false : 'inline-cheap-module-source-map';
    config.optimization = production ? minimizerBlock : {};
    return config;
}
```

Далее, когда мне надо захватить `audio-file`, ну или `jpg | png` файл, я в главном `JS` файле я его импортирую.

```
import frederic_chopin from '../binary/audio/frederic_chopin_-_adazhio.mp3';
```

И тут возникает резонный вопрос. Когда файл один ну или даже пять, это терпимо.
А допустим у меня **500** файлов. Не импортировать же мне их все в ручную?!

Вопрос, как импортировать много файлов?

Можно ли импортировать сразу все содержимое какой-то определенной папки?

Comment: [Webpack: Dependency Management](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/)

Comment: @Grundy, благодарю, уже неделю документацию читаю, видать туда еще не добрался...  Не видел этого раздела

Comment: @Air получается уже ответ есть ? 

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, нет... Пока ковыряюсь, вникаю...  Если можешь ответить отвечай

Comment: такого очевидного и умного для этой задачи решения найти сложновато.Можно как вариант написать (отделить) все импорты в одном файле и экспортировать потом из отдельного js-файла и работать над ними.

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, пока думаю и разбираюсь... Не готов к конструктивной беседе (обсуждению) данного вопроса...

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, но если что пиши, буду рад разного рода мнению

Comment: @Grundy, разобрался, благодарю еще раз.  Кстати не хочешь написать ответ с подробностями... Боюсь у меня красиво не получиться... Я технический добился желаемого результата... Но на практике (пока что) не смогу объяснить, что, да как, пока не пойму  как все работает внутри...

Comment: @Air, не разбирался. Если заработало - напиши что сделал и как заработало

Comment: @Grundy,  написал...

Comment: Если задача - скопировать файлы в готовый бандл, то есть же copy-webpack-plugin (а вообще mp3-файлы в вебпаке это ОЧЕНЬ странно)

Comment: @andreymal, не разбирался с этим плагном еще... Почему странно? Можно поподробнее...???

Comment: @andreymal, может ответишь тогда на вопрос...   Ты умеешь подробно, я знаю...)))

Comment: Не отвечу, потому что я не знаю реальной задачи и просто подозреваю проблему XY)

Comment: @andreymal, ок...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ по сути чисто технический. Простите не могу подробнее, пока не вник глубже.

Все просто

```
let audioFiles = []; 

function importAll(r) {
  r.keys().forEach((s, i, arr) => audioFiles[i] = r(s));
}

importAll(require.context('../binary/audio/', true, /\.mp3$/));
console.log(audioFiles);
```

И в итоге получаем это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и далее делаем с этим массивом что хотим