# Как отсортировать массив страниц?

Tags: javascript, html

Коллеги, на сайте есть страницы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не важно какая функция, но есть функция, которая считывает наличие страниц и возвращает массив (этих самых страниц), и в соответствии из данных которого я уже создаю объект с нужными мне данными.

```
let _getPages = [];

pages.forEach((s, i, arr) => {
    _getPages[i] = {
        href: s.split('/')[2].split('.')[0].capitalize(),
        link: s
    }
})
```

Получаю такое:

```
{href: "About_us", link: "frontend/pages/about_us/index.html"}
{href: "Contact", link: "frontend/pages/contact/index.html"}
{href: "Main", link: "frontend/pages/main/index.html"}
{href: "Slider", link: "frontend/pages/slider/index.html"}
```

Далее, имея все это я создаю ***Меню*** на странице

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
const menu = document.querySelector('menu');


_getPages.forEach((s, i, arr)=>{
    let listPage = li.cloneNode(true);
    listPage.classList.add('listPage');
    listPage.innerHTML = s.href
    menu.appendChild(listPage);
})
```

И в итоге, что у меня есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге, не могу сообразить, как именно и на каком уровне с сортировать 
так, чтобы  я получил ***меню*** С той последовательностью страниц которую хочу.

Допустим, чтобы `Main`, был на первом месте, `About_us`, на последнем....

> P.S. Первое что пришло в голову, это добавить в название папок буквы
>   `a, b, c, d.....`, а потом их срезать, но не думаю, что это
>   профессиональный подход

Вопрос немного глуповат, но не соображу ни как.

***Не прошу готовы пример, мне нужна лишь подсказка.***

Так как и на каком уровне отсортировать массив?

Comment: Мне кажется проблема в том, что мы изначально не знаем как сортировать.... То есть у нас есть некий список меню, который отсортирован по алфавиту.... Но откуда js знать, как расположить элементы? В текущим случаи я вижу, что нужна сортировка массива на основе другого массива. То есть где-то заранее объявить массив меню с нужным порядок..... Но мне кажется, что в вашем случаи может не подойти. Пример сортировка массива по другому массиву тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array/13304870#13304870

Comment: _С той последовательностью страниц которую хочу._ - а как ты определяешь с какой хочешь?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, ты не знаешь отсортирован ли полученный список

Comment: @Grundy, в том то и дело что не знаю как определить.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev. естественно `JS` не может знать как расположить, пока я ему не опишу логику. А чтобы была логика, я не могу сообразить из каких исходных данных описать логику для `js`.

Comment: @Grundy. Если буду знать из каких исходных данных отталкиваться, то написать код не проблема... Вот и вопрос, что будет грамотнее использовать как исходник?

Comment: Все упирается в место, где ты хочешь это настраивать. Жестко забивать порядок в имя папки - это один вариант, но в случае добавления не в конец нужно будет переименовывать несколько папок. Можно хранить обычным массивом в скрипте, можно массивом в конфиге, можно просто отсортировать по алфавиту, либо вообще не сортировать, и положиться на то, что отдаст функция которая собирает эти файлы

Comment: @Grundy, где не важно. и как не важно. Больше всего мне надо знать что будет грамотнее использовать как исходные данные, от чего отталкиваться

Comment: @Air, что значит _грамотнее_? Варианты я описал выше, определись с требованиями к своей задаче и выбери вариант наиболее удовлетворяющий этим требованиям. Так как в вопросе требования не представлены, сейчас это действительно выглядит как: _беременная блондинка, которая не знает чего хочет... То ли арбуз с цементом, то ли мармелад с опилками..._

Comment: @Grundy, то есть,  если взять переименовать папки так как я хочу, что они шли в той последовательности и  за основу взять название для сортировки, это будет правильное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, следует признать, что порядок - не единственная информация которую вам не удалось получить. Ещё вам нужны нормальные заголовки (*"About us"* пишется без подчёркивания!), перевод их на другие языки, цвет...

Проще всего - не играться с автоматическим определением страниц сайта, а записать всё меню в отдельный файл.

Если же такой вариант не устраивает по каким-то причинам (например, из-за раздельного деплоя) - нужно добавить файл с описанием к каждой странице. Пусть у вас будут файлы `pages/about_us/info.json`, `pages/contact/info.json` и т.п. Дальше можно завести для каждой страницы атрибут `order` и сортировать по нему.

Как вариант, всю необходимую информацию можно попытаться добавить в мета-тэги. Но тут вам понадобится уже парсер html чтобы её прочитать.

Comment: Pavel, что касается заголовков, это пока не важно, я прекрасно знаю как пишется `About us`...  Я не прав в том, что несколько не глубоко вопрос описал. Тот изначальный массив который я получаю, это работа `webpack` в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936622/webpack-4-Как-импортировать-файлы-если-их-много/936675#936675 есть пример того, как я получаю массив.  Мне не хочется в ручную описывать все это. Я как только создаю некую папку с новой страницей, у меня динамический перезаписывается массив и я получаю список страниц

Comment: @Air я понял что это работа webpack. Но зачем вам использовать то решение для жалкой менюшки на 4 пункта? А если надо позарез - положите json рядом с каждой страницей.

Comment: Pavel, я согласен на все сто с этим высказыванием `...для жалкой менюшки на 4 пункта...`.  Но тут есть несколько глубокий смысл. Я пока еще учусь.  Я умею многое, но это моя первая самостоятельная сборка всего `frontend backend`, `webpack`... Так что, это может быть не обязательно меню, данный пример я могу использовать в чем то другом. По этому каждый ответ мне интересен и важен.  Есть о чем подумать... В любом случае благодарю за ответ

Comment: отдельный order в каждом файле надо как-то синхронизировать будет

Answer (score 0):

```js
const menuIWant = ["Main","Contact","Slider", "About_us" ];
let _getPages = [
  {href: "About_us", link: "frontend/pages/about_us/index.html"},
  {href: "Contact", link: "frontend/pages/contact/index.html"},
  {href: "Main", link: "frontend/pages/main/index.html"},
  {href: "Slider", link: "frontend/pages/slider/index.html"},
];

const result = [];

menuIWant.forEach(item => {
  for (let i=0; i<_getPages.length; i++){
    if (_getPages[i].href === item) {
       result.push(_getPages[i]);
       break;
      }
    }
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Минус не мой. Я и не собирался ставить, но это не то. У меня этот массив создается динамический. Когда я создаю новую папку, то `webpack` мне все перебирает, с данным примером, мне придется лазать в код и добавлять в список `const menuIWant = ["Main","Contact","Slider", "About_us" ];` новое значение в ручную

Comment: Что бы получить, что хочешь - нужно знать, что хочешь). В любом случае, эту информацию нужно будет где-то хранить. Если Вы добавите какой-нибудь индекс к названию файлов, то потом, если захотите изменить меню, прийдется переименовывать все файлы. С массивом будет проще

Comment: Дмытрык, по моему ты щас меня сравнил с беременной блондинкой, которая не знает чего хочет... То ли арбуз с цементом, то ли  мармелад с опилками...))))

Comment: Ставлю плюс, так как все же твой вариант имеет право на жизнь... Но не в моем случае

Comment: Зачем делать `forEach` и `push` когда существует `map`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, все зависит от опыта. Для меня, такая реализация более очевидна. Спасибо, за `codereview`)