# webpack4 компилирует не все HTML файлы

Tags: javascript, html, webpack4

> Я изначально не верно понял суть проблемы, правлю вопрос, что бы точнее сформулировать проблему...

Есть такая сборка ***`webpack`***:

```js
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');


const minimizerBlock = {
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        warnings: false,
        parse: {},
        compress: {},
        mangle: true,
        output: null,
        toplevel: false,
        nameCache: null,
        ie8: false,
        keep_fnames: false,
      },
    }),
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
  ]
}

const config = {
  entry: {
    main: './frontend/src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    port: 8888,
    overlay: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8889'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "less-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      //{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|webp)$/, loader: 'url-loader', },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|webp)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/binary/image/')
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'image/[name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/binary/fonts/')
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp3)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/binary/audio/')
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'audio/[name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/')
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: './index.css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src/', 'template.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
      favicon: 'frontend/binary/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png',

    }),

  ]
};
module.exports = (env, options) => {
  let production = options.mode == 'production';
  config.devtool = production ? false : 'inline-cheap-module-source-map';
  config.optimization = production ? minimizerBlock : {};
  return config;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть `папке src - файле template.html`, в которой есть такая часть верстки

```
 <div id="root">
   <img src="${require(`../binary/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png`)}" alt="" />
</div>
```

который после компиляции  `webpack`

перевоплощается в `index.html  в папке public` я получаю такой результат

```
<div id="root">
  <img src="images/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

И все работает.

Параллельно `src` есть папка `pages` разными страницами, в которых есть такой же кусок верстки

```
<header>
   <img src="${require(`../../../../binary/image/sheelak/0viber-image.jpg`)}" alt=""/>
</header>
```

и после запуска `webpack` создается папка с этими файлами и вот результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И далее проблема `require` для `img` который в `header` не срабатывает

получаю ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что не так с моим `webpack`????

Аналог вопроса на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509572/webpack4-how-to-require-a-photo-for-dynamic-added-html-files)

Comment: а зачем там require вообще? вроде как вебпак сам может разобраться

Comment: @Grundy, я вопрос не верно поставил. там проблема не в том, что файлы грузятся, а в том  что те `html` файлы которые при сборке создаются отдельно отдельно вот для них `require` не срабатывает

Comment: Я вот собирался вопрос править, так ты мне написал коммент...

Comment: @Grundy, правил вопрос

Comment: @Grundy, глянь, может подскажешь чего...

Comment: ну как минимум странное окончание имени файла `%60)%7D` -> `\`)}`

Comment: @Grundy,  я такое окончание файла встречал, когда подключал  в главном `html` в теге `img - картинку ` без `require`- а вот  с этими сторонними файлами не работает

Comment: Что только не перепробовал...

Comment: Я не могу понять суть...

Comment: @Grundy, Вот щас сижу разбираюсь с `html-loader`, мне тут подсказали

Comment: @Grundy, нутром чую, что я не верно `html` компилирую... Его надо как `css` - грубо говоря... При компиляции `css` весь грузиться в главный `JS` , а потом `css-loader` его обратно в один файл отдельный `css` преобразует

Comment: А в данном примере `html`  просто как картинки или музыку кидаю в `public` если он импортирован. А импортирую его в `js-E`. Помнишь ты мне помог с импортом?

Comment: не помню что там было

Comment: @Grundy, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936622/webpack-4-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/936675#936675

Comment: погуглите `processCssUrls: false`

Comment: @Air У вас `template.html` обрабатывается через `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, а файлы из папки `pages` через `file-loader`, он видимо не обрабатывает каждый файл как точку входа. Нужно прогнать все файлы через `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, тогда должно быть норм.

Comment: @kost1k  Почему не ответом а комментом?

Comment: @Air Ну я думаю этого не достаточно для ответа. Сейчас если получится найти пример как это реализовать, напишу в ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался проще, чем я думал...

Подробнее написать не могу, так как сам еще толком не разобрался...

Подробно можно посмотреть [тут в принятом ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509572/webpack4-does-not-compile-all-html-files) , все работает как надо....

```
       {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/')
        ],
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                loader: 'extract-loader'
            },
            {
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    interpolate: true,
                }
            }
        ],
        exclude: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src/', 'template.html')
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В *`html-webpack-plugin`* есть возможность генерировать несколько HTML страниц:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), // Generates default index.html
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ // Also generate a test.html
        filename: 'test.html',
        template: 'src/assets/test.html'
    })
]
```

Можно попробовать создать свой экземпляр плагина для каждой страницы таким способом, но в данном случае придется хранить страницы в одной директории, т.к. перебирать их в ручную думаю не вариант, а как побороть вложенность я к сожалению не подскажу(

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');

    function generateHtmlPlugins(templateDir) {
        const templateFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, templateDir));
        return templateFiles.map(item => {
            const parts = item.split('.');
            const name = parts[0];
            const extension = parts[1];
            return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: `${name}.html`,
                template: path.resolve(__dirname, `${templateDir}/${name}.${extension}`)
            })
        })
    }

    const htmlPlugins = generateHtmlPlugins('./frontend/pages');

    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
        ]
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: './index.css',
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src/', 'template.html'),
                filename: 'index.html',
                favicon: 'frontend/binary/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png',
            }),
        ].concat(htmlPlugins)
};
```

Видимо это не поможет решить проблему, т.к. файлы разбросаны по разным папкам, сразу не обратил на это внимания, но возможно поможет подобраться к решению)

Comment: Не то... Не работает...